# Unable to view output when using VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Attempting to webscrape AHA for clinical guidelines. Upon running code, there seems to be no problems, but no output is shown in both the output and terminal windows. Terminal window simply returns the folder my file is saved in.

Code attached:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys

def get_clinical_guidelines():
"Returns a list of clinical guidelines from the American Heart Association website."

url = "https://professional.heart.org/en/guidelines-and-statements"
response = requests.get(url, timeout=5)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

guidelines = []
for guideline in soup.find_all("div", class_="row guideline-item"):
  title = guideline.find("h4").text
  link = guideline.find("a")["href"]
  guidelines.append({"title": title, "link": link})

return guidelines

def main():
guidelines = get_clinical_guidelines()
for guideline in guidelines:
print(f"Title: {guideline['title']}")
print(f"Link: https://professional.heart.org{guideline['link']}")

 if __name__ == "__main__":
 main()

get_clinical_guidelines()
```

Comment: `soup.find_all("div", class_="row guideline-item")` does not return anything! It can't find any element!

Comment: The return value of the method `get_clinical_guidelines()` you defined will not be printed, you need to use print() to obtain it

Answer (score 0):

The function get_clinical_guidelines() is invoked separately at the end of the script, but the return value of this function is neither received nor used, so its result will not be printed out. If you want to view the result of this function, you need to print out its return value, like so: print(get_clinical_guidelines()).